# Display a string backwards using recursion and substring method

Tags: java, recursion, substring

I'm currently having trouble solving my code and its issue. I am trying to create a method that displays a string backwards with recursions and using substring. For Example if my I put "10 ten" as my argument, it should reverse word and repeat the letters 3 times.

it would show up like this:
nnneeettt

Here is part of my method that focuses on that part.

```css
public static String method3(Integer num,String line)
   {
       //base case
      if (line.length() == 1)
         //return line + line + line;
         return line.substring(line.length()) + line.substring(line.length()) + line.substring(line.length());
       //recursive case 
      else{
      
         return method3(num,line.substring(1)) + line.charAt(0) + line.charAt(0) + line.charAt(0);
      }
   }//end of else
```

My output is showing up this:

```css
nnnee
```

it's missing one more 
"e" and 3 more "t"s at the end

edit:

This is my 2nd method that does "10 ten" repeats the words twice instead of thrice and not reverse

```css
public static String method2(Integer num, String line)
   {
       //base case
      if(line.length() == 1)
         return line + line;
        
       //recursive case
      else{
         return line.substring(0,1) + line.substring(0,1)
                   + method2(num,line.substring(1,line.length()));
      }//end of else
   }//end of method2
```

output:
tteenn

Comment: You want to display the string backwards, so surely "10 ten" would become "net 01"?  What did I miss?

Comment: @jconder i added another code that does it straight without doing it backwards

Comment: What does the `num` parameter do?

Comment: it's a separate parameter from my method. I have 5 methods but I am specifically having issue on my 4th method which is this one

Comment: Ah, it will help in general to get faster and more accurate responses if you keep stuff that isn't relevant to your question out of the problem.  It also is generally useful for self debugging to try to isolate the problem in it's most reducible form, a lot of times that will help you see the issue you are having clearly which might help you find an answer as well.

Comment: @AmmarSamater i edited my code btw ! output is showing "eeettt" all it's missing now is the 3 n's

Comment: @jconder I'll keep that in mind sir ! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way to do it:

```
private static String reverse(String string) {
    if(string.length() == 1)
        return string + string + string;

    else 
        return reverse(string.substring(1)) + string.charAt(0) + string.charAt(0) + string.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: i did your method and i got "eeettt" as my new output...only missing the 3 

nnn

Comment: oops nevermind ! You are correct ! my .substring method is messing things up

Comment: did you save after you copied my method? I just tested it again, it the out put is nnneeettt

Comment: Ok good. glad to help. Keep in mind that for big strings, there will be many objects created. Three will be created for each recursion.